# Elementary Linear Algebra Question

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, real-numbers

Given $a_{ij},x_1,x_2\in{}\mathbb{R}$, it is reasonable to interpret the system

$$a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2=0$$
$$\vdots{}$$
$$a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2=0$$

as describing $m$ lines in the plane, all of which pass through the origin.

**Question**: If instead $a_{ij},x_1,x_2\in{}\mathbb{C}$, what is the visual interpretation, if any?

**Follow up**: Does an equation $a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2=0$ with $a_{1},a_{12},x_1,x_2\in{}\mathbb{C}$ always describe a line in the complex plane? Example:

$$ix_1+(2-3i)x_2=0$$

How do I plot the graph of this equation in the complex plane? Basically it feels like two dimensions are not enough.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello Mr. Community Bot. I do not think I can be any more specific or detailed. This is a pretty simple question.

Comment: Well, this is the same interpretation, except that the lines and the planes are complex...

Comment: Hello TheSilverDoe: thank you for your response. Does an equation $a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2=0$ with $a_{1},a_{12},x_1,x_2\in{}\mathbb{C}$ always describe a line in the complex plane? Do you know of any resources for visualizing this?

Comment: @Gary What do you call the complex plane ? If you think of $\mathbb{C}$ as a plane, then you are missing my point. What I am saying is that the equation $a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2=0$ defines a complex line, i.e. a complex vector space of dimension one, so something that looks like $\mathbb{C}$. And this line can be embedded in a complex plane, i.e. in a vector space of dimension $2$ over $\mathbb{C}$, so something that looks like $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Very interesting response. Thank you. So you are defining a "complex line" as an abstraction of a 2D line, often not something that we can graph in a 2D plane. Correct?

Comment: The solution manual of the book I am reading (Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze) claimed that "[The homogeneous system in the OP] consists of a set of lines through the origin (0, 0) in the x-y plane". To me, this seems very misleading and perhaps just wrong, even allowing the abstract definition of "line" that you're using.

Comment: @Gary Indeed. About the claim in your book, it is true if by "$x-y$ plane", one means that $x$ and $y$ are two *complex* coordinates. But in that case, you cannot draw it on your paper : or if you draw it, you have to imagine that each axis is a copy of $\mathbb{C}$ (and not $\mathbb{R}$), and be careful of the danger of this representation.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of visualization, two complex variables would require 4 axes, which we can't do in our 3-d world. The only alternative I can see is to make a series of 3-axis charts in which e.g. each one has a different fixed value for the imaginary of x1 ; then the real of x1 is on one axis and x2 is plotted on the other two axes (one for real, one for imaginary).

Comment: Thanks. I have no experience visualizing complex functions and the solution manual of the book I am reading (Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze) claimed that "[The homogeneous system in the OP] consists of a set of lines through the origin (0, 0) in the x-y plane". To me, this seems very misleading and perhaps just wrong. It seems there are a couple of popular books out there ("Visual Complex Functions" by Wegert and "Visual Complex Analysis" by Needham) that can help with the visualization part.

Comment: I googled 'visual complex functions' and, in addition to the book you mentioned, a good video appeared: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtoIXhUgqSk

Comment: Is this what you are saying?  For a function $f(z)$ where $f(z),z\in{\mathbb{C}}$, make two plots:  $f(a)$ versus $a$ and $f(b)$ versus $b$ where $$a, b, f(a), f(b)\in{\mathbb{R}}$$ $$z=a+bi$$ $$f(z)=f(a)+i*f(b)$$.

Comment: More like  $$x + y*i = f(a + b*i)$$  then plot x,y,a on three axes for different values of b.